# How do I get Max() from 100+ fields in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django-rest-framework, max, highest

The table has 110 fields. I need to highest value from each row (like gratest in mysql) from 100 columns (thousands of records) and I need the filed name well (which has the highest value) Work platform in Django, MySQL.

I've tried hitting db from view but that just slows down.

1. How do I do this in view ?
2. Is there any other alternative ?